# ctype equivalent of the variable type word

Tags: python

What's the ctype equivalent in python for these variable types:

```
signed short iHD;
word iThem;
```

word is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned short word
```

Definition of unsigned 16-bit type

Looked everywhere but I cannot find the equivalent ctype

Thanks!

Comment: `word` isn't a standard type... what is it defined as?

Answer (score 0):

`signed short iHD` is [c_short](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_short)

`word iThem;` is [c_ushort](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ushort)

Note that these are the `short` types as defined by your platform, which will probably be 16 bits but not definitely!

Ifyou want exactly 16 bit types then use [c_uint16](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint16) and [c_int16](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint16)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation?

You are looking for the `c_short` and `c_ushort`

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_short
http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ushort